# Install Beta By Crashlytics On Custom ROM

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-android

[image] Background:

We have a POS Android Terminal with custom Firmware and OS. For apk installation on the device we are using tool provided by the manufacture which digitally signs the apk.

Problem:

I signed the Beta By Crashlytics app using our tool and installed it on our device.
But after launching the app... I get "Install Update" prompt. Any ideas ? Are such devices supported?

Update: the "Install Update" is being prompted by the Beta By Crashlytics app.

Note: I'm already using latest version 1.7.0

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Sorry, I'm not quite understanding the problem. It sounds like for the APK install, the manufacture used an older version of your app and when you launched the app installed via Beta a new version of the app was available which is why the prompt showed up.

Comment: Nope... What I have done is. I've singed the apk using my manufactures tool and then loaded on the device.. And the version is 1.7.0

Comment: Updated question

Comment: In this case, we think there is a new version of the app available to test, but I'll admit the setup you described is not something we've tested against.

Comment: Also I don't get this popup when I use version 1.6.1.2... Looks like there is a hash check in code of apk for new version.

Comment: If a new version of the app is ready and you haven't explicitly installed an older version of the app through Beta, then when we will check and see if a new version is ready to be installed. If so, we'll show that prompt.